# How to pass the parameters into solnl() function in R?

Tags: r, optimization

I have the non-linear optimization problem

[image]

I have tried to use the `solnl()` function from the `NlcOptim` package. 
Unfortunately, I don't know how to pass the param into the `solnl()` function correctly.

And I have the

```
Error in objfun(X) : argument "param" is missing, with no default
Calls: solnl -> objfun
```

**My code is below:**

```
library(MASS)
library(NlcOptim)

objfun=function(x, param, n){
return( x[n] * (param[1] - param[2] / sum(x[1:(n-1)])  ))
}

#constraint function
confun=function(x, param, n){
f=NULL
f=rbind(f, x[n] - param[1] + param[2] * sum(x[1:(n-1)]))
return(list(ceq=f, c=NULL))
}
A <- 1; B <- 1
param = c(A, B)

x0=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
n <- length(x0)

solnl(x0, objfun=objfun(x0, param, n), confun=confun)
```

**Question.** How to pass the parameters into function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used `solnl` from `NlcOptim` BUT I've used `optim` from `stats` and I think the functioning is simlar.

I think you should do something like

```
solnl(x = x0, objfun = objfun, confun = confun)
```

Unfortunately, I don't see in the help page any way to pass further arguments to the objective or constraint functions as it is possible in `optim` through `...`. None of the examples of `solnl` have such a possibility illustrated. Thus, I don't think you can pass `param` and `n` to `solnl`.

If it is just for a personal script and not for a package or something more formal, maybe you can define your objective function and constraint function just in terms of the decision variables `x`. If you define `param` and `n` before calling `solnl` it should work:

```
# functions defined just in terms of decision variables
objfun <- function(x) {
  return( x[n] * (param[1] - param[2] / sum(x[1:n-1])  ))
}
confun <- function(x){
  f <- NULL
  f <- rbind(f, x[n] - param[1] + param[2] * sum(x[1:n-1]))
  return(list(ceq = f, c = NULL))
}

# starting points
x0 = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)

# deifning any parameter before calling solnl
A <- 1; B <- 1
param = c(A, B)
n <- length(x0)

# resolving
solnl(x = x0, objfun = objfun, confun = confun)
```

**Edit**

`optim` does not allow constraints appart from constant lower and upper bounds for the decision variables. I think `nloptr` might do the work for you. Take a look at the example in page 4 of [`nloptr`'s manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/nloptr.pdf). The difference is that `nloptr` does receive `...`, meaning that you can pass further arguments to the objective and constraint functions at the end of the call.

Thus, you can define your objective and constraint functions receiving `param` and `n` as arguments

```
objfun <- function(x, param, n) {
  # fill this
}
confun <- function(x, param, n) {
  # fill this
}
```

and then use

```
nloptr(x0 = x0, eval_f = objfun, lb = rep(0,n),
       eval_g_eq = confun, param = param, n = n)
```

Take care to modify your confun function according to the requirements of `nloptr`. Use the example in the provided link for that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The solnl() function is not the requirement. Could you show how to use optim() in my case?